Pointwise convergence of sequence of continuous functions to a continuous function
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ at every rational number. Can we conclude that $\{f_n\}$ converges at every point to $f$?
I can show this result under an additional assumption that all these functions, $f_n$, $f$, are increasing (decreasing). For this, consider any $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Because $f$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$, pick rational numbers $r < x < q$ such that $f(q) - f(r) < \epsilon$. Then,
\begin{equation}
f_n(r) - f(q) \leq f_n(x) - f(x) \leq f_n(q) - f(r),
\end{equation}
which implies $$- \epsilon \leq \liminf_n f_n(x) - f(x) \leq \limsup_n f_n(x) - f(x) \leq \epsilon.$$ Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we know that $\lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$. Without monotonicity, I do not know how to establish similar inequality as above.

One more example to show that under no additional assumptions, $f_n$ need not converge to $f$ at all $x$.
Define
$$f_n(x) = \cos^{2n}(n!x\pi).$$
Let $f(x) = 1$. Then, at each rational number $x$, $f_n(x)$ converges to $1=f(x)$. But $f_n$ does not converge to $1$ (or even doesn't converge at all) for all irrational numbers.

Unfornunately without further assumptions like moniticity, or  uniform convergence on $\mathbb{Q}$ (not sure for the latter) you can't obtain the result.
Consider the following sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ defined by:
$$\begin{array}{lll}
f_n(x) = n(x+1-\pi)^n &\text {for}& \pi-1 \leq x \leq \pi\\
f_n(x) = 0 & \text{for} & x<\pi-1\\
f_n(x+\pi) = f_n(\pi-x)
\end{array}$$
They verify $\forall x \neq \pi$, $f_n(x) \to 0$, but $f_n(\pi) = n$ does not converge.
